# VS_ISBROKEN error when i try to connect odata in ssis

Tags: ssis, odata, microsoft-dynamics, axapta, dynamics-365

i was using odata source in ssis to get my dynamics 365 data. when i configure connection and click preview i am able to see sample data. but after i connect my source to ole db destination or sql destination or any other component that is able to get input, my odata source raise an error with no other explanation.

because of that i tried to change some configuration settings. tried so many things but none of them helped.

basically i want to know what configuration should i use to write my odata source to ole db destination. because i think the problem comes from odata source.

can anyone help?
thanks in advance.
one of the errors below:

```
> TITLE: Package Validation Error
> ------------------------------
>
> Package Validation Error
>
> ------------------------------
>ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
>Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Destination [260]]: The number of input columns for OLE DB >Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input] cannot be zero.
>
>Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "OLE DB Destination" failed validation and returned >validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
>
>Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.
>
>Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.
>
> (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)
>
>------------------------------
>BUTTONS:
>
>OK
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: there is no code. i just use ssis with odata source